# Disabling backspace and delete in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I'd like to disable the delete and backspace keys in Atom. I'm using it to write fiction, and I'd like to emulate the feeling you have when you use a typewriter and you can't go back and edit what you just wrote.
Any idea how I might do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should do your homework before posting a question on StackOverflow, this is covered well enough by the [Atom Flight Manual](https://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/):

> When the keymap system encounters a binding with the `abort!` directive as its command, it will stop searching for a keybinding. For example, the following code removes the keybinding for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> when the selection is inside an editor pane:
>
> ```coffee
> 'atom-text-editor':
>   'cmd-o': 'abort!'
> ```

Special keys are also covered on that page: `enter`, `escape`, `backspace`, `delete`, `tab`, `home`, `end`, `pageup`, `pagedown`, `left`, `right`, `up`, `down`, `space`

Putting it all together, this is what you're looking for:

```coffee
 'atom-text-editor':
   'backspace': 'abort!'
   'delete': 'abort!'
```

If you're using Atom only for writing, the above should be sufficient. Otherwise, I suggest combining the selector with a grammar scope as described [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/#selectors-and-custom-packages).